# Differential equation $f(x) = 1 - x\int_{1}^x f(t)dt$: alternative approach

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Suppose we have the following differential equation:

$$a)\;\; f(x) = 1 - x\int_\limits{1}^{x}f(t)dt$$

and a solution:

$$b) \;\; f(x) = xe^{(1 - x^2)/2} - xe^{-x^2/2}\int_\limits{1}^{x}t^{-2}e^{t^2/2}dt$$

which has the properties that (i) it is continuous for $x > 0$ and (ii) it satisfies (a).

I need to find all functions that satisfy both properties (continuous on $x > 0$, and solve (a)). However, my answer is wrong. Cannot figure why.

I define $y = \int_\limits{1}^x f(t)dt$. Then the part (a) becomes:

$$y' = 1 - xy \Rightarrow y' + xy = 1$$

Now, I assume that for the point $a = 1$, $y(1) = b$. I use the standard solution formula for the linear differential equation of the first order:

$$P(x) = x; Q(x) = 1; A(x) = \int_\limits{1}^xtdt = x^2/2 - 1/2$$

and the solution is:

$$y = be^{1/2 - x^2/2} + e^{1/2 - x^2/2}\int_\limits{1}^xe^{t^2/2 - 1/2}dt$$

If we differentiate this, we arrive at $y' = f(x)$, which is:

$$f(x) = y' = -bxe^{1/2 - x^2/2} - xe^{1/2 - x^2/2}\int_\limits{1}^xe^{t^2/2 - 1/2}dt + 1$$

But this answer does not give anything resembling (b), since the latter has $t^{-2}$ factor under the integral sign. Moreover, the book says that the function (b) is the ONLY solution, which my answer clearly does not agree with, since I have a constant $b$, which can be manipulated to give a different answers.

Can someone specify what is wrong in this proof (it is not finished yet, I seem stuck)? Is it possible to prove this by continuing this approach I am taking (you can show how)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integral equation/ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860828/integral-equation-ode)

Comment: @Axion004, I saw that answer, this one is not a duplicate. I would like to understand what is wrong with my proof, and see its solution continued. This is why I added the tags proof-verification, and proof-explanation.

Comment: Here is what I am getting: the general solution to $y' + xy = 1$ is $y(x)=(\int^x_1 e^{t^2/2}dt+c)e^{-x^2/2}$ and if $y(1)=b$ then $b=ce^{-1/2}$ so $y(x)=(\int^x_1 e^{t^2/2}dt+b\sqrt e)e^{-x^2/2}$

Comment: a) You have initial values for $f$ and $y$: $f(1)=1$ and $y(1)=0$. This gives a single value for $b$.  b) To go from (b) to your formula, use integration by parts.

Comment: @Helmut, yes indeed. So, it was in fact the correct solution: just that the b is constrained - I did not notice that I could definitively find it from simple substitution into the original formula. Actually by "reverse"-integration as you suggested, I got my answer from (b) then. Thx :) How did you see that it had to be integrated from (b) back to my solution? :) I think if I could notice at once that I had to integrate (b) by parts, I could find my solution then, I just did not see the pattern.

Comment: @John: If you have two correct formulas for a unique solution, then they must be equivalent. Integration by parts was the only way I could imagine between (b) and your solution. You can, of course, also start with your solution and obtain (b) by integration by parts,but this is less natural: you have to factor $e^{t^2/2}=t^{-1}\cdot te^{t^2/2}$...